refreshing matplotlib's FigureCanvasQT results in the figure being drawn partially off screen
I'm repeatedly drawing a matplotlib multiplot using FigureCanvasQTAgg and Pyside6. Rather then updating the data, I'm removing all axes and completely redrawing the figure on each refresh, since the number and layout of subplots may be different on each refresh. On the first draw, the figure nicely fits the parent window, but on redraws the figure partially falls of screen. Resizing the window makes the figure snap to the window size again. How do I make it properly fit the parent window?
Here is a minimal example:
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)

    def setup(self, nrows: int, ncols: int) -> None:

        self.fig.set_size_inches(4 * ncols, 6 * nrows)

        for sample_idx in range(nrows * ncols):
            ax = self.fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, sample_idx + 1)
            rand_image = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 200))
            im = ax.imshow(rand_image, origin="lower")
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(
            left=0.05, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2
        )


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.setup(2, 2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.show()

        # Setup a timer to trigger the redraw by calling update_plot.
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        for ax in self.canvas.fig.get_axes():
            ax.cla()
            ax.remove()
        rows = np.random.randint(1, 3)
        cols = np.random.randint(1, 4)
        self.canvas.setup(rows, cols)
        self.canvas.draw()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()


Why are you calling set_size_inches()? Remove that, and it should work as expected. If you want a default size, either use self.resize() in the main window, or eventually override the canvas sizeHint().

@musicamante What I wanted to achieve in the actual application is that the matplotlib figure stretches horizontally to fit the screen, but vertically there can be a scroll bar if the figure is too high (if there are a lot of rows in the layout)

@musicamante you are right simply removing set_size_inches() seems to solve the problem. If you want to write this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

I would like to, but my answer would be limited to removing that line without providing further explanation about why it doesn't work as you expected, as I have very limited experience with matplotlib. Most importantly, it's not really clear to me how the "inch" unit is considered in visual/widget coordinates, and how it would actually affect both width/height ratio and the possibility of scrolling. Call me old fashioned (and often unnecessarily prolix), but I don't like to provide answers without proper explanations :-)
